# UIMenuController submenu

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller, mac-catalyst, uimenuitem

I'm trying to implement an `UIMenuController` with some `UIMenuItems` in a Mac Catalyst app with the following:

```
let menu = UIMenuController.shared
menu.menuItems = [itemA(), itemB(), itemC()]
menu.showMenu(from: someView, rect: someView.bounds)

// itemB and itemC are just as the following
private func itemA() -> UIMenuItem {
    let item = UIMenuItem(title: "Some item", action: #selector(test))
    return item
}
```

The menu is shown but I cannot find a way to create submenus, for example:

`itemA()` expands for `itemB()` and `itemC()`

How can I achieve this?

Example image[image: example]

Comment: You can’t do that with UIMenuController, you have to use the new context menu system: https://kylebashour.com/posts/context-menu-guide